# How to distinguish plain quoted string and template literal(backtick)

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

They are the same in the result, but they have different abilities. Is there any way to identify between them so that I can restrict the user(of a function) to use only template literal as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like an imaginary `isFromTemplateLitteral` boolean?

```
function(string){
  if(string.isFromTemplateLitteral()){
    // console.log("YES!")
  }
}
```

No can do.
Because the string was passed to the function using reference in the memory stack for it. So even before the function body starts running, `string` is already a *normal* string. **A primitive with type string**.

There is no way to know how it has been constructed (template litteral, concatenation, simple/double quotes, etc.) or where it really comes from (user input, harcoded text, regular expression match, etc).

Answer (score 1):

No, not really... just like you can't really differentiate `5` and `4 + 1`.